# Electret analog of Curie temperature

Tags: electrostatics, material-science, polymers

If you heat a permanent magnet above its Curie temperature then individual dipoles re-align to cancel each other out and it loses its strength.

An [electret](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electret) is the electrical analog of a permanent magnet, typically made by cooling a polymer in an environment of a high electrostatic charge density.  It is formed by melting, so there has to be a temperature where the bulk resistivity and dielectric constant decrease enough that the charge loss becomes catastrophic.

What is that electret analog of the Curie temperature called?
Where can I read more about it?  Are there references?

I was thinking that the electron diffusion in polymer (PTFE) might try and follow something like [Fick's second law](https://www.comsol.com/multiphysics/diffusion-equation).  The rate of diffusion is also going to be a function of temperature, time, and initial charge.